# Starting a new FragmentActivity without content view shows non-transparent view

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, setcontentview

I open this simple fragmentActivity without setting any contentView

```
public class InternalDummyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //
  }
}
```

But I still see a blank view is opened. Why is that?

I have thought if there is no `setContentView` then the activity is transparent.

is it because of the fragmentActivity? How do I create a transparent fragmentActivity then?